# How to show image in the place of creating message in androidX..?

Tags: android, android-layout, kotlin, androidx

I am creating an offlline SMS app.In that I have to place the option of selecting an image button and after selecting image I want to place it at the position of sending image.But do not understand how to adjust the imageView button to get desired layout.Someone can help me..?

I have searched a lot but found nothing.

**XML FILE**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">
    <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:padding="5dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:gravity="left"
            android:orientation="horizontal" tools:ignore="MissingConstraints" android:id="@+id/linearLayout">

        <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/inbox_thumb"
                android:layout_width="60dp"
                android:layout_height="60dp"
                android:src="@drawable/circle"/>
        <TextView
                android:hint="Phone Number"
                android:layout_width="5dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="6dp"
                android:padding="10dp"
                android:textStyle="bold"
                android:textSize="15dp"
                android:gravity="left"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:id="@+id/phone" android:layout_weight="1"/>


    </LinearLayout>


    <androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView android:layout_width="384dp"
                                               android:layout_height="661dp"
                                               android:scrollbarAlwaysDrawVerticalTrack="true"
                                               android:id="@+id/reyclerview_message_list"
                                               android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
                                               android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
                                               app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                                               app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
                                               app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
                                               app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/linearLayout">

    </androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView>

    <View android:layout_width="0dp"
          android:layout_height="2dp"
          tools:ignore="MissingConstraints"
          android:background="@color/colorPrimaryDark"
          android:layout_marginBottom="0dp"
          app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/message_area"
          app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
          app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent">
    </View>

    <LinearLayout android:layout_width="0dp" android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                  android:id="@+id/message_area"
                  android:orientation="horizontal"
                  android:minHeight="48dp"
                  android:background="#ffffff"
                  app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
                  app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
                  app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
                  tools:ignore="MissingConstraints">
        <Button
                android:text="attach img"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:id="@+id/btn1"
        />
        <EditText
                android:id="@+id/txtMessage"
                android:hint="Enter message"
                android:background="@android:color/transparent"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="16dp"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:maxLines="6"/>
        <ImageView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content" app:srcCompat="@mipmap/ic_launcher" android:id="@+id/imageView2"
                android:layout_weight="1"/>
        <Button
                android:id="@+id/btnSend"
                android:text="SEND"
                android:textSize="14dp"
                android:clickable="true"
                android:layout_width="64dp"
                android:layout_height="48dp"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:layout_gravity="bottom" />
    </LinearLayout>
</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

**Expected**

[image: Expected]

**Actual**

[image: Actual]

Comment: You want to display your image in the write message field ?

Comment: Yes just like it is in the expected image..

Comment: Multiple images or single ?

Comment: Right now just need single image

Comment: Is it possible to send multiple images..?

Comment: Okay writing solution for single image

Comment: if you want to display on single create layout image and text and hide the layout .on select image set layout visible and render image and text. if multiple images then create horizontal recyclerview with image and text

Comment: @KIRANCSN I do not understand what you want to say.Can you show me in the form ofcode..?

Comment: @NarenderNishad do you know some solution..?

Comment: @aisha submitted my solution using your code and optimizing it for you. please check it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have created a basic template using your Layout in AndroidX. You can beautify it using your style, icons and colors accordingly. Please copy it and look at it in your Android Studio.

```
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">

<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/linearLayout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:gravity="left"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:padding="5dp"
    app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent">

    <androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatImageView
        android:id="@+id/inbox_thumb"
        android:layout_width="60dp"
        android:layout_height="60dp"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher" />

    <androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatTextView
        android:id="@+id/phone"
        android:layout_width="5dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="6dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:gravity="left"
        android:hint="Phone Number"
        android:padding="10dp"
        android:textSize="15dp"
        android:textStyle="bold" />


</LinearLayout>


<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/message_area"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:padding="10dp"
    android:background="@drawable/rounded_rect_shape"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent">


    <androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatImageButton
        android:id="@+id/btn1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher" />

    <androidx.cardview.widget.CardView
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        app:cardBackgroundColor="@android:color/darker_gray"
        app:cardCornerRadius="6dp"
        app:cardElevation="2dp">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatImageView
            android:id="@+id/imageView2"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            app:srcCompat="@mipmap/ic_launcher" />

        <androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatEditText
            android:id="@+id/txtMessage"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="16dp"
            android:background="@android:color/transparent"
            android:hint="Enter message"
            android:maxLines="6" />

    </LinearLayout>

    </androidx.cardview.widget.CardView>

    <androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatButton
        android:id="@+id/btnSend"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:text="SEND"
        android:textSize="14dp" />
</LinearLayout>

<View
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="2dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="0dp"
    android:background="@color/colorPrimaryDark"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/message_area"
    app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"/>

<androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
    android:id="@+id/reyclerview_message_list"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
    android:scrollbarAlwaysDrawVerticalTrack="true"
    app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@id/message_area"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/linearLayout"/>
```

Comment: Glad to hear that. :)

Comment: But why I get `android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher" ` as error..?

Comment: you can change it with you image or icon

Comment: android:background="@drawable/rounded_rect_shape" is also geting as error

Comment: you can remove that line

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/198365/discussion-between-narendernishad-and-aisha).

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, you're trying to place the "imageView2" ImageView on top of the "txtMessage" EditText, is that right?

If that's how it is, what you need to do is wrap both of them in a vertical LinearLayout, like so:

```
    <LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical">

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/txtMessage"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="16dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:background="@android:color/transparent"
            android:hint="Enter message"
            android:maxLines="6" />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/imageView2"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            app:srcCompat="@mipmap/ic_launcher" />
    </LinearLayout>
```

Comment: I have applied thos method but I got the same answer

Comment: I get the same actual layout which I don't want

Answer (score 0):

```
  <LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:gravity="bottom"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:padding="8dp">

    <ImageButton
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@drawable/circle_drawable"
        android:backgroundTint="@android:color/black"
        android:padding="8dp"
        android:layout_margin="8dp"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_add_black_24dp"
        android:tint="@android:color/white" />

    <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:cardBackgroundColor="@android:color/darker_gray"
        app:cardCornerRadius="6dp"
        app:cardElevation="2dp">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical">

            <ImageView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_margin="8dp"
                android:src="@mipmap/ic_launcher" />

            <RelativeLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:orientation="horizontal"
                android:gravity="bottom"
                android:weightSum="1">

                <EditText
                    android:id="@+id/et1"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_toStartOf="@+id/ib2"
                    android:layout_margin="8dp"
                    android:text="Hello" />

                <ImageButton
                    android:id="@+id/ib2"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:background="@drawable/circle_drawable"
                    android:backgroundTint="@android:color/black"
                    android:padding="8dp"
                    android:layout_margin="8dp"
                    android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
                    android:src="@drawable/ic_send_black_24dp"
                    android:tint="@android:color/white" />

            </RelativeLayout>
        </LinearLayout>
    </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>

</LinearLayout>
```

[image: Image attched]

I have used background drawable, you can replace with your add and send image.
Hope it solves your problem.